# Run Python on MaxScripts

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

I want to run Python on 3Dsmax 2014. I saw the website and know 3Dsmax 2014 can use the Python script . But when I try with example from the website, it does not work. Maybe lack of some software or anything else.

I used this code in "MAXscript Listener":

```
python.Execute "print 'hello'"
```

And result was:

```
-- Unknown property: "execute" in undefined
```

So , someone can guide me how to use the Execute ?
Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 2):

You would need the Extension 1 (Subscription Advantage Pack) to be able to run python scripts like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load python first. Try this:

```
python.init()
python.execute "print 'Hello World'"
```